# Content Editable Method Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

while working on my website I came across an odd problem for some reason I cant get the `contenteditable="true"` command to work on my heading with the id "hl" if anyone could help me get it working that would be awesome. I just want the contenteditable command to work so that I can change the HLHLHL text within the website.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>ID</title>
</head>

<body>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: lightgray;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .dropbtn {
      position: relative;
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: black;
      top: 1px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 260px;
      left: 645px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    }
    .dropbtn2 {
      position: relative;
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: black;
      top: 1px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown2 {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content2 {
        position: relative;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 260px;
      left: 700px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content2 a {
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
    }
    .dropbtn3 {
      position: relative;
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: black;
      top: 1px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown3 {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content3 {
        position: relative;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 260px;
      left: 745px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content3 a {
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown3:hover .dropdown-content3 {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown3:hover .dropbtn3 {
    }
    .dropbtn4 {
      position: relative;
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: black;
      top: 1px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown4 {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content4 {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 260px;
      left: 790px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content4 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown4:hover .dropdown-content4 {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown4:hover .dropbtn4 {
    }
    #code {
            position: relative;
            top: 300px;
            left: 600px;
        }
        #lang {
            position: relative;
            top: 201px;
            left: 655px;
            font-size: 38px;
        }
        #con {
            position: relative;
            top: 202px;
            left: 700px;
            font-size: 38px;
        }
        #x {
            position: relative;
            top: 202px;
            left: 745px;
            font-size: 38px;
        }
        #g {
            position: relative;
            top: 202px;
            left: 790px;
            font-size: 38px;
        }
        #hl {
            position: relative;
            top: 380px;
            left: 1070px;
            font-size: 38px;
        }
  </style>

  <h1 id="hl" contenteditable="true">HLHLHL</h1>

  <h1 id="code">NL⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀-</h1>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><h1 id="lang">L</h1></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <button id="U" onclick="changeU()">U=NFPA (USA)</button>
      <button id="E" onclick="changeE()">E=ISO (Canada)</button>
      <button id="F" onclick="changeF()">F=ISO (French)</button>
      <button id="S" onclick="changeS()">S=Spanish</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown2">
    <button class="dropbtn2"><h1 id="con">CON</h1></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content2">
      <button id="OH2" onclick="changeOH2()">Diamond 2/3/Diamond Care</button>
      <button id="OHP" onclick="changeOHP()">Diamond 2/3/DC-Plug & Play</button>
      <button id="OH1" onclick="changeOH1()">Diamond 1</button>
      <button id="NCG" onclick="changeNCG()">Chemetron 400</button>
      <button id="NC5" onclick="changeNC5()">Chemetron 500</button>
      <button id="C73" onclick="changeC73()">Series 73</button>
      <button id="CLI" onclick="changeCLI()">Litharge Series</button>
      <button id="CSA" onclick="changeCSA()">Series A</button>
      <button id="AMI" onclick="changeAMI()">Amico</button>
      <button id="BSB" onclick="changeBSB()">Beacon Series B</button>
      <button id="DIS" onclick="changeDIS()">D.I.S.S</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown3">
    <button class="dropbtn3"><h1 id="x">X</h1></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content3">
      <button id="Q" onclick="changeQ()">Ohmeda</button>
      <button id="C" onclick="changeC()">Chemetron</button>
      <button id="D" onclick="changeD()">DISS</button>
      <button id="P" onclick="changeP()">Puritan Bennett</button>
      <button id="O" onclick="changeO()">Oxequip</button>
      <button id="XS" onclick="changeXS()">XS</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown4">
    <button class="dropbtn4"><h1 id="g">G</h1></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content4">
      <button id="O2" onclick="changeO2()">OXY</button>
      <button id="A" onclick="changeA()">MEDICAL AIR</button>
      <button id="V" onclick="changeV()">VAC (2 PORT ONLY)</button>
      <button id="2" onclick="change2()">N20</button>
      <button id="C2" onclick="changeC2()">CO2</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeU() {
      document.getElementById("lang").textContent = "U";
    }
    function changeE() {
      document.getElementById("lang").textContent = "E";
    }
    function changeF() {
      document.getElementById("lang").textContent = "F";
    }
    function changeS() {
      document.getElementById("lang").textContent = "S";
    }
    function changeOH2() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "OH2";
    }
    function changeOHP() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "OHP";
    }
    function changeOH1() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "OH1";
    }
    function changeNCG() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "NCG";
    }
    function changeNC5() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "NC5";
    }
    function changeC73() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "C73";
    }
    function changeCLI() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "CLI";
    }
    function changeCSA() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "CSA";
    }
    function changeAMI() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "AMI";
    }
    function changeBSB() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "BSB";
    }
    function changeDIS() {
      document.getElementById("con").textContent = "DIS";
    }
    function changeQ() {
      document.getElementById("x").textContent = "Q";
    }
    function changeC() {
      document.getElementById("x").textContent = "C";
    }
    function changeD() {
      document.getElementById("x").textContent = "D";
    }
    function changeP() {
      document.getElementById("x").textContent = "P";
    }
    function changeO() {
      document.getElementById("x").textContent = "O";
    }
    function changeXS() {
      document.getElementById("x").textContent = "XS";
    }
    function changeO2() {
      document.getElementById("g").textContent = "O";
    }
    function changeA() {
      document.getElementById("g").textContent = "A";
    }
    function changeV() {
      document.getElementById("g").textContent = "V";
    }
    function change2() {
      document.getElementById("g").textContent = "2";
    }
    function changeC2() {
      document.getElementById("g").textContent = "C";
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove all the unnecessary code.  We only need the code segment that pertains to your problem.  And please add in the code for the method you're referring to, and explain what results you expect from that method.

Comment: I'm not sure where the issue is coming from exactly so I thought Id leave everything just so people could see everything.

Comment: We don't even know what the issue is because you haven't explained what is supposed to be happening .  And you mention a method but there's no code for that method.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: No.  What exactly is supposed to happen when you say: "I cant get the contenteditable="true" command to work".  What is supposed to happen?  And where is the code segment that pertains to whatever is supposed to happen?

Comment: I want the ```<h1 id="hl" contenteditable="true">HLHLHL</h1>``` to work normally, right now it does not let you edit the text even though contenteditable is set to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the seconf h1 of this pair:

```
  <h1 id="hl" contenteditable="true">HLHLHL</h1>

  <h1 id="code">NL⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀-</h1>
```

It is positioned to overwrite the first header.

You can experiment in your browser's devtools by making the second of these h1s have display: none - then you will be able to click on the first.

the layout is a bit odd, as if the NL bit with the dashes has been shoved in as an afterthought. A re coding of that whole part might be a good idea, to get everything into a logical order.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it.

Comment: <3⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀